# Angular NgRoute not loading partial in Electron App

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, electron

I'm currently working on a simple Electron desktop app, using Angular version 1.3.0. I am using NgRoute to switch between a main.html and settings.html view. This works fine when tested in a locally run server, but when run through Electron the link which is meant to load the settings view leads to a blank page.

I've set the base tags href to './' and the main.js and vendor.js are being loaded in fine. Below is the code from the Angular app.js file.

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('AppApp', [
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/settings', {
        templateUrl: 'views/settings.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
  });
```

And here is the index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <base href="./">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="AppApp">    
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally the main.html (Which loads when the electron app starts with no problems) with the link used to the load the settings view.

```
<div hm-dir='hm-dir'>
    <a href="/settings"><img id="logo" src="images/logo-anchor_32x32.svg"/></a>
    <div id="swipe-mask">
       <h1>App</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to disable html5 mode in electron.

Comment: I've tried disabling html5 mode and removing it all together, along with the base href, but still the same results. The index.html loads in the main.html view without a problem but all goes blank when I click on the link.